# Adding points to QgsRubberBand polyline instead of giving list of points

Tags: qgis, pyqgis-3, mapping, plot, qgsrubberband

```py
canvas = iface.mapCanvas()
polyline = QgsRubberBand(canvas, False)  # False = not a polygon
points = [QgsPoint(1,1), QgsPoint(2,2), QgsPoint(3,3), QgsPoint(4,4)]
polyline.setToGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(points), None)
polyline.setColor(QColor(255, 0, 0))
polyline.setWidth(3)
```

This is my sample code. I want to be able to append points to the line rather than updating my list and providing the same list again. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new point to the existing rubber band using `addPoint` method.

For example: `polyline.addPoint(QgsPointXY(10,4))`

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How could I not see that. *facepalm*